# Как работает авторизация на сервере (логин/пароль)?

Tags: android, https, auth

Клиент-серверное приложение. 
Решили сделать на сервере авторизацию по логину-паролю.
Мне не понятен сам механизм как это работает. Каков должен быть мой алгоритм действий в этом случае.
Более-менее разобрался как подключиться к серверу по http, получить данные json, распарсить и показать в листвью.
А вот с авторизацией затык вышел.
Буду рад конструктивному ответу.

Comment: Я в Java EE не силен, но, если я не ошибаюсь, в этом может помочь конкретный фреймворк (если он полностью не решает данную задачу).

Comment: это мобильное приложение.

Comment: Именно сервер и задает правила авторизации.

Comment: единственное что мне известно и понятно на данном этапе, что авторизация по логину и паролю. Этого достаточно, чтобы успешно решить поставленную задачу?

Comment: Смотрите: сервер пишет какой-то человек и он делает авторизацию, как может. А Android-клиент уже авторизуется так, как позволяет это делать сервер. Сервер может предлагать авторизацию хоть на сокетах, поэтому однозначного ответа быть не может. Посмотрите или попросите документацию к Вашему серверу и, исходя из нее, делайте авторизацию.

Comment: есть два варианта - в одном логин-пароль передается с каждым запросом (плохо, но просто). Во втором - логин-пароль передается один раз, а сервер возвращает некий "токен" - строку. Эту строку и нужно передавать с последующими запросами. Сервер сам сопоставит строку-токен с запомненными и разрешит/запретит. Все другие способы сводятся к этим двум, отличаются только тем, как именно имя-пароль передаются и как именно возвращаются ответы.

Comment: @KoVadim отлично! уже что-то! пытаюсь самостоятельно гуглить этот вопрос, но никак не могу найти толковой статьи на русском. Не пинайте, мне б по-русски разобраться в этом для начала...

Comment: А научились делать обычные http get/post запросы и получать на них ответы?

Comment: @KoVadim get научился. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Допустим, что get/post уже умеете делать (post нужно объязательно научиться, так как get запросы могут кешироваться и все запросы, которые изменяют данные - не должны использовать get).

Итак, при старте приложение должно проверить, если в настройках сохранненный ключ (у нас это будет просто строка). Если есть, то пробуем им выполнить тестовый запрос, передав его как то на сервер. Если это get запрос, то можно передать в параметрах урла:

```
http://example.com/rest/init?key=123123123&data=testtest
```

здесь 123123123 - это ключ (как его получить - будет ниже). а data = testtest - какие то произвольные данные. Ну мало чего нам понадобиться. Но для этого запроса может и не быть больше данных. Другие запросы выглядят точно также, только урл изменяется. Например, выбрать из базы данные по продавцу boo может выглядеть так

```
http://example.com/rest/vendor?key=123123123&name=boo
```

на стороне сервера нужно прочитать этот ключ. И проверить. Сами ключи можно хранить в базе. Допустим, что на сервере у нас php (а он там обычно и есть). Поэтому, нужна функция проверки ключа

```
function check_key($key) {
  # делаем запрос к базе,
  # проверяем и возвращаем
  return true; # false
}
```

а в начало каждой защищенной функции вставляем такое

```
if (!check_key(_GET['key']) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    return;
}
# все ок, можно сделать запрос и отдать данные
```

я специально возвращают 401 код, который значит то, что ключ плохой или не верный. По хорошему, эти две ситуации нужно различать. Но "и так сойдет(с)".

Клиент, получив ошибку, должен либо прекратить попытки, либо попросить пользователя ввести имя пароль (и потереть старый ключ, если он  был).

Теперь осталось последнее - нужно по имени-паролю получить ключ. Со стороны клиента все просто - передаем в каком-то виде их на сервер. Очень хочется это все запихнуть в get запрос:

```
http://example.com/rest/get_key?login=user&password=pass
```

Но это **НЕПРАВИЛЬНО**. Правильно передавать внутри post запроса. Тут есть много способов, например, передать как [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/how-to-send-post-request-in-json-using-httpclient) или как [обычную форму](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202163/send-form-data-post-request-using-http-post-in-android).

На стороне сервера этот конткретный урл не должен быть защищен кодом выше (как бы это не казалось очевидным, но многие делают подобную ошибку и долго удивляются). Как вычитать имя пароль, проверить их по базе - это просто - обычно один запрос. Если все ок - просто возвращаем назад ключ (который нужно не забыть запомнить в базе, а то как проверять?).

Но где же взять сам ключ? Самое простое - сгенерировать его [случайным образом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator). самый простой-простой вариант - md5 от текущего времени (но это плохой вариант - злоумышленник может попробовать угадать его).

Да, описанное здесь слишком примитивно и для многих покажется слишком утрированным. Но оно нужно для того, что бы понять базу.

Многие думают, что для мобильного приложения нужны какие то особые технологии/методы. Это не правильно. При правильном подходе, серверу все равно, кто к нему подключается (но это не значит, что мобильному клиенту можно отправить пару гигов json просто так). Поэтому, с серверной стороны не нужно искать "особого специалиста".

Что нужно научиться делать на клиенте:

- объязательно:

  - http get/post запросы
  - сохранять данные  в локальной базе/конфигах
- желательно:

  - генерировать/парсить json/xml
  - освоить потоки или async

Answer (score 2):

Опишу стандартный механизм авторизации через пару `login/password`:

1. Нужен *https* - если его нет, то все делается по другому
2. Формируем json строку содержащую пару login/password и шлем серверу
3. Сервер генерирует `hash(password+salt)` - `hash()` - обычно что-то типа `PBKDF2`
4. Сервер смотрит у себя в БД по ключу login и находит хэш `password+salt` сравнивает его с вычисленным на шаге 3.
5. Если авторизация успешная, сервер генерирует случайный `token`, который отдает обратно клиенту
6. Далее клиент все свои запросы сопровождает полученным от сервера токеном, если запрос приходит без токена или токен просроченный - запрос отклоняется.

Comment: скажите, а что делать в случае просроченного токена и кто определяет скрок жизни токена?

Comment: у меня же это все описано:) если токен просрочен - либо генерируется новый токен (с запросом логина-пароля), либо пользователь идет лесом (тут как ТЗ напишут).

Comment: Срок жизни токена определяет сервер конечно же. Его можно синхронизировать с временем жизни http сессии.

Answer (score 0):

Для авторизации клиента и идентификации его как пользователя, за частую используют куки (Cookie).

В них передает "ключ", как правило session_id - который генерируется при подключении клиента к вашему http серверу. так же value данной куки передается в БД, storage ( по вашему желанию ) как идентификатор пользователя. Само собой, у каждого клиента свой уникальный session_id

Comment: у меня же мобильное приложение...