# Хранение ключа для авторизации

Tags: php, mysql, авторизация

Пытаюсь реализовать авторизацию на сервере из android-приложения по алгоритму из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/645466/235436) ответа.
Хотелось бы узнать больше о том, как хранить ключи для авторизации на сервере.

Сейчас я добавил в основную таблицу с пользователями 2 столбца: для ключа и времени последнего действия.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно хранить не сам ключ, а его хэш, полученный, например, методом [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php)? Но тогда, чтобы не выбирать для проверки все ключи из базы, нужно ещё слать на сервер логин? В ответе по ссылке про логин ничего нет. Или нужно делать как-то иначе?

Comment: Не-не, ключи/токены хранятся как есть без всяких хэшей

Comment: Если авторизация подразумевается по логину и паролю, то на сервере хранятся логины и хеши паролей. Для авторизации передаёте логин и пароль, а на сервере проверяете соответствие пароля логину.

Comment: @Pyramidhead, эт я понимаю. Если всё верно, я генерирую ключ, заношу его в базу и посылаю в ответе. Я думал, что нужно их, также как и пароли, хранить в хэшах.

Comment: Ну практического смысла я в этом не вижу. Если переживаете за безопасность, можете использовать второй ключ, который не будет передаваться от клиента серверу, но им будут подписываться все передаваемые данные, а сервер, в свою очередь, будет эту подпись проверять.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону JWT авторизации. Сам JWT передается в http заголовке Authorization. В JWT токен можно зашить время жизни и пользовательскую инфу, типа его ID и т.п. Реализовано множество библиотек под разные ЯП